# Handlebars DateTimeFormat Helper

Tags: c#, handlebarshelper, handlebars.net

I want to display a Datetime as MM-yy format with [Handlebars](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Handlebars.Net/) and found
the [Moment-Helpen](https://github.com/helpers/helper-moment) but its JS not C# in NuGet there is Moment.js which we 
can install but don´t know how to use it.

The solution should be something like:

```
<div>{{formatTime dataDate "MM-YY"}}</div>
```

I think I have to register some helper with Moment but don´t know how. 
May someone help me?

Comment: This does not make sense to me, please provide a simple reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Handlebars.Net my solution is:

```
            Handlebars.RegisterHelper(DateFormat, (output, context, data) => 
            {
                DateTime.TryParse(data[0].ToString(), out DateTime date);

                var dictionary = data[1] as HandlebarsDotNet.Compiler.HashParameterDictionary;
                var formatString = dictionary["formatString"];

                output.WriteSafeString(date.ToString(formatString.ToString()));
            });
```